# How to cut your own hair?

Tags: hair

With most of the World's citizens no longer being able to visit the hairdresser for quite some time, we need to know how we can cut our own hair. This is particularity a problem for those people who live alone, who under the current rules are not allowed to let other people cut their hair.

Comment: If you live alone and are not going out, why do you need to cut your hair?  In the next month it will grow maybe half an inch (1.5cm).  Personally I do cut my own hair and have been for doing it for years, but does it need to be done, if you are in lockdown for a month?  I don't think so.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Some of us have hair that tangles horribly when it gets too long. Personally, I would just use a hair trimmer to buzz it short, then wait for the end of the pandemic to get a barber to make it look nice.

Comment: Put a band around your head until your hair is long enough to bunch.

Answer (score 2):

I use hair clippers from Walmart, they cost about 20 or 30 dollars. They last for years.

If your hair is long comb it out, I don't let mine get long enough to comb.  I cut it once a month or so.

I put the number 2 clipper guard thing on the clippers.

I bring the vacuum cleaner into the bathroom, and get completely naked.  This makes cleaning up the hair easier.  I use the bathroom mirror, so I close the sink drain, I don't want hair going down the drain.

Turn the clippers on and start clipping.  The number 2 guard, gives you a short military style buzz cut that looks clean.  You can start wherever you want, the front and sides are pretty easy.  The back and top, just keep bringing the clippers up from the back of your neck and over the top.  You want to cut into the grain, so if the hair lays down, cut up.

Everyone is different, for me there is some hair at the temple that grows at a weird angle and I have to pay particular attention there, and take the clippers in from a couple different ways.

Trying to get a razor cut or taper on the back of your head is just not going to work.  Go with the number 2 guard everywhere.

There are a few hairs around the back of my ears that hard to get.  I take the guard off and use bare blade (this still leaves maybe 1/8 inch of stubble) and very carefully fold my ear forward with one hand, and try to get those hairs to stand up.  I very carefully run the clippers along the back of my ear.  Just one corner of the clipper touching my skull.  You can also use the bare blade for nose and ear hair.

Between running my hand over my head, and trying to see the back of my head in the mirror, I get all the high spots.  It is not hard, but is a little nervous making the first couple of times.  Start to finish time is about 15 minutes.

When I am done cutting, I use the vacuum to get most of the hair off of me, off the floor, and out of the sink.  Wipe everything down, then jump in the shower.

It might seem like shaving bald would be easy, but it is not. The clippers without the plastic guard (bare blade) leave stubble that is a few days worth of growth, and it is a pain to shave.  If cut shorter then the number 2 guard, your hair is like a little pin cushion, and when you go to bed, your head sticks to the pillow.